# Can I set the Sequelize default useMaster is true

Tags: sequelize.js

My team want to set read replication for some tables, but we don't want to change the default set.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
const options = {
  username: 'DATABASE_USERNAME',
  password: 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
  database: 'DATABASE_NAME',
  port: 10,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  dialectOptions: {},
  replication:{
     read:[{host:"read-host"}], // required
     write:{host:"write-host"} // required
  },
  socketTimeout: 120000
}
const sequelize = new Sequelize(options.database, options.username, options.password, options);
```

How can I do it?

The table default read the master node

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const options = {
  username: 'DATABASE_USERNAME',
  password: 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
  database: 'DATABASE_NAME',
  port: 10,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  dialectOptions: {},
  replication:{
     read:[{host:"read-host"}], // required
     write:{host:"write-host"} // required
  },
  query: {
    useMaster: true // required
  },
  socketTimeout: 120000
}
const sequelize = new Sequelize(options.database, options.username, options.password, options);
// default table
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define(
    'test',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: 'test'
    }
  );
};
// use master
test.findAll()
// use replica
test.findAll({useMaster:false})

// default use replica DB
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define(
    'test2',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: 'test2',
      defaultScope: {
        useMaster: false
      }
    }
  );
};
// use replica
test2.findAll()
// use master
test2.findAll({useMaster:true})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).